# Getting 403 Forbidden on Twitter API v2 following Endpoint

Tags: python, postman, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I've purchased the Basic plan for Twitter API v2. I forked Twitter's public workspace on Postman to test out the different endpoints I need for my project. When I tried the

`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/:username`

It worked and I get the user id. However when I try other end points like:

`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/followers`

OR

`https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/following`

I get the following response:

```
{
    "client_id": "27723471",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

I have created my app inside a project and you can see the settings in the image below:

[image]

I have regenerated the API key, API secret, bearer token, access token and access token secret before and after changing the app settings. I have deleted and recreated it, I have deleted and recreated the project about 10 times now with every permutation but the error doesn't seem to go away. I wrote some code in Tweepy uses the :id/following endpoint and not to my surprise it gives the same error.

Tweepy code:

```
# Set up Tweepy API client
client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret,
                       access_token, access_token_secret, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Initialize tables for TinyDB
predefined_tweets_table = db.table('predefined_tweets')
liked_tweets_table = db.table('liked_tweets')
commented_tweets_table = db.table('commented_tweets')

MY_HANDLE = "xxxxxx"
MY_ID = xxxxxxx


def get_following():
    paginator = tweepy.Paginator(
    client.get_users_following,            # The method you want to use
    MY_ID,
    max_results=10,                       # How many tweets per page
)
    for page in paginator:
        print("\npage",page)
        print("\npage.data",page.data)                       # The tweets are here
        print("\npage.meta",page.meta)                       # The count etc. are here
        print("\npage.includes",page.includes)                   # The includes are here
        time.sleep(15)
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the info here https://twittercommunity.com/t/get-2-users-id-following-is-now-broken/197526

https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/followers
https://api.twitter.com/2/users/:id/following

These above endpoints were removed by Twitter on June 26 and ironically enough you can still see them in the official documentation!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).